# Can't figure out CSS positioning issue

Tags: html, css

My CSS positioning skills are very poor and I just cannot figure out why these two text boxes won't be on the same line. Basically I'm trying to make two text boxes that fit on the same line and will use overflow to add in a scroll bar.

Why are they refusing to lineup next to each other? I can use absolute positioning, but that screws up the page when I change the browser size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MCrav Resume</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="title">Matthew Cravinhos Resume</h1>

    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>  
        <li><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="extra.html">Extra Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>


    <img src="profile_pic.jpg" alt="Picture of Matthew Cravinhos" id="pic">


    <div class="text_group">
        <div id="about">
            <h3>About me</h3>

            <p>Here is a section about me. I can fill this in later. Here is         some more text because I need to test width.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="interests">
            <h3>Personal Interests</h3>

            <p>Here is the section about my interests. Again this is some more text to test width.</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    border: 1px solid #EA5911;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li{
    display: inline;
}

.navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#pic {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: #EA5911;
}

.text_group {
    width: 40%;
}

#about {
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#about h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

#interests {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
}

#interests h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: have a link to a online version ?

Comment: To troubleshoot CSS Positioning, one of the easiest techniques to apply is to draw a colored box around the element.  For example, use outline:  1px red solid; on the HTML element of your choice.  Start drawing boxes.  See if your items have the boundaries that you expect.

Comment: Also, you have one item floating left and the other item floating right.  Watch your floats.  If you want to see those floats in action, experiment with a lot of junk text in that division, but not in either of those elements.

Comment: I have created borders for both, I just for some reason can't figure it out. The only thing that seems to work is absolute positioning but I need to learn how to do this without taking the items out of the flow to avoid overlapping when the browser size is changed.

Comment: By time time I was done experimenting, they provided the correct answer about the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough room for the boxes to be next to each other, so they are wrapping.

For instance, The wrapper has `width: 40%`.

You can make that `width: 100%;` and give the two floated children a width that fits that:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4vc9scc/1/)

```
.text_group {
    width: 100%;
}

#about {
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}
#interests {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
}
```

You can play with the width sizes as desired, but the sum of the two children's width cannot exceed the parents width in order for them to be side by side.

Comment: Hmmm halfway there, for some reason the blocks aren't on the same line though. Should they be if I am floating them with the proper width values? The interests section is aligned properly but its on the next line

Comment: Oh wait I got it, for some reason position: relative was screwing it up. Why was this so?

Comment: I don't really have an answer for that because its on the same line for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/sjvd9gbt/

The biggest issue was that the div surrounding the elements was set at 40%, so there wasn't enough room for them to sit side by side- they defaulted to stacking on top of each other.

```
.text_group {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `box-sizing: border-box;` then your div can be 50% width. And your div's are on the same line. These does the trick:

```
.text_group > div {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1r25v64L/)

Comment: Ahhh thats new and pretty cool, is that the better way to go about it?

Comment: With `box-sizing: border-box;` your container can have paddings and borders and are ever 50% width. The solution will never break on small screens or window widths like other solutions above.

Comment: Really that is awesome to know, just to clarify what do you mean when you say break? Are you talking about overlapping or the boxes losing shape on smaller screens?

Comment: To illustrate the behavior I create this fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/aevct38k/1/ More information about box-sizing you can get on https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/